# How can I change a property on a shared material depending on the object?

Tags: materials

I've just started using blender after using Cinema 4d for years. I have this trivial problem that I can't work out how to solve.

I have a material that I want to use on multiple objects, however I want to change the tiling of the material on depending on the object. In Cinema 4d I would just select the material tag on the object and change the tiling. I cant work out how to do the blender equivalent of this without making global changes to the material.

Answer (score 4):

One way you can do this is to utilize the object's **Pass Index** located in the **Object Properties** tab under **Relations**. Set the **Pass Index** to whatever scale multiplier you want per object.

[image]

Set up your material to use the **Object Info > Object Index** output as the input to **Mapping > Scale**.

[image]

You will now have one material scaled differently for multiple objects.

[image]

Comment: Oh, this is a smart way to do it :).

Answer (score 0):

**Properties** editor ***>*** **Data** properties (green icon currently) ***>*** **Texture Space** tab.

Uncheck `Auto Texture Space` and edit position and scale.

BUT.. you will need a Texture Coordinate and Mapping for that to work